# Pandas - Use Value in Column as key in separate dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the key is a name and the value is another dictionary. For example:

```
dict1 = {name1: {...}, name2: {...},...}
```

I also have a Pandas dataframe `df` with columns 'A', and 'B'.
I would like to add a column to the dataframe using those column values as keys in `dict1`.
For example, for each row the value in 'A' to be used as the key in `dict1` and the value in 'B' to be used as the key to the inner dictionary, with the result being put in column C.

I am trying things like `df[C] = dict1[df[A]][df[C]]` or `df[C] = df[[A,B]].apply(lambda x,y: dict1[x][y])` but nothing seems to be working. Ideally I would like do this without looping through the rows without something like `df.itertuples()`.

Example df row (A, B):

```
'key1' | 'key2'
```

I want the following (A, B, C):

```
'key1' | 'key2' | dict1['key1']['key2']
```

Comment: Please post a testable example with your expected output , in other words a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just posted an example row of what I have vs. what I want. Please let me know if more is needed.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close - just need to modify your code for `apply`. Try `df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: dict1[row.A][row.B], axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pd.concat` to create a dataframe with all your dictionaries, then `rename_axis`, `reindex` and `reset_index` like:

```
#dummy example
df  = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('aaabbc'), 
                    'B':[0,1,0,0,1,1]})
dict1 = {'a': {0:3, 1:5}, 'b': {0:1, 1:8}, 'c': {0:2, 1:6}}
# do the job
df_f = pd.concat([pd.Series(d, name='C') for d in dict1.values()], 
                 keys=dict1.keys())\
         .rename_axis(['A','B'])\
         .reindex(df[['A','B']]).reset_index()

print (df_f)
   A  B  C
0  a  0  3
1  a  1  5
2  a  0  3
3  b  0  1
4  b  1  8
5  c  1  6
```